# Objective C - Convert char[] to NSString in Hex format

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, hex, string-formatting

I have a problem I need to convert char [] to String, hexadecimal format

Example

```
Nsstring * result;
char[4]={0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04};

///    convert  --   char[] -> Nsstring in Hex format

Nslog(@"%@",result);
```

expected output:  "01020304"

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this:

> ```
> NSMutableString * result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
> char cstring[4]={0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04};
> ///    convert  --   char[] -> Nsstring in Hex format
> int i;
> for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
>     [result appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x",cstring[i]]];
> }
>
> NSLog(@"%@",result);
> [result release];
> ```

Comment: +1, but it would be better to use `initWithCapacity:` to avoid reallocations, since you know how long the string is going to be.

Comment: Then you probably would also want to do [result appendFormat:@"%02x",cstring[i]]; to avoid the extra string allocation.

Comment: If you need uppercase, and all 3 in a row, like I do, "%02X%02X%02X" is the correct string for that.

Answer (score 4):

The formatter "%02x" will display an individual character as 2 digits of zero-padded hex. Simply loop though your array and build the string with them.

Comment: I like that this explains what %02x means